# how to add custom data with product name in invoice email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, invoice, email-templates

i want to add brand name with product name in invoice email. when i check the `email/order/invoice/item.phtml`.i see this .

```
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
```

how to change to get my required data. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy

`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\invoice.phtml` to
`app\design\frontend\{{your package}}\{{your theme}}\template\email\order\items\invoice.phtml`

Now you can place your brand with `$_item->getBrand()` after `$_item->getName()` in line no. 31 for magento 1.9.2.1.

if your brand attribute code is brand then `$_item->getBrand()` value getting.Otherwise you have to set your custom attribute name.

Comment: already figure that out

Comment: you have to dump $_item array and got for brand value is available or not in that array.If getting brand value then you can use it.